# When does a fetus become conscious?

Tags: brain, reproduction

I thought of asking this question in the Psychology & Neuroscience stack exchange, but I ultimately decided this would be a better stack exchange for it. When do the "lights turn on" in a fetus, that is, when does it come into existence as a conscious being? I have heard stories of people remembering things while in their mother's womb, so presumably they were conscious of it, even if very faintly. So, does consciousness begin at birth, or before, and if so, how much before? I have heard that brain activity happens in the fetus some weeks after conception, so does that mean it is conscious then, however dimly?

Comment: Which of the many extant definitions of consciousness are you referring to? Even legal definitions vary with jurisdiction. Can you edit to be specific.

Comment: Sometimes I think back on how I perceived certain things as a child and think that I was perhaps barely even conscious then. One issue is that your question seems to be associating memory with consciousness. Just because I don't remember eating breakfast last week doesn't mean I wasn't conscious then. Perhaps I wasn't. Who knows? I can't remember after all.

Comment: @JiminyCricket I am defining consciousness as the capacity to experience anything, be it a sight, or a sound, or a touch, or some other sensation.

Comment: A bacterium can respond to the chemicals.  Is that not consciousness by your definition?

Comment: By that definition, the gametes are conscious before they even meet, so prior to conception presumably.

Comment: Probably need to start over at [Philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/) to ask if consciousness exists. Your definition is insufficient at best. What does it mean to "experience" something? Is it merely sensing of one's environment? Does a plant sensing and responding to stimuli exhibit consciousness? Maybe. Is "brain activity" pre-requisite to experience? Is a cultured synapse firing in a petri dish conscious?

Comment: Basically, the upshot is that it seems biologists don't have the foggiest idea when anything becomes conscious.  There are still arguments about whether various *animals* are conscious - and I mean things like fish or insects, not microbes or other things that don't have an obvious nervous system.

Comment: It might work here if you change the parameters of the question a bit. Were you to ask what the developmental milestones are which mark a *qualitative and/or quantitative* increase in awareness or neural activity... You'd need to specify an end-date as of course it continues into adulthood - and at a range of different timescales per individual. Of course, you'd need to show prior research as per the [help]'s [ask] section. I'm sure you could get a fairly comprehensive and *factual* answer then, without all the equivocation about definitions.